# How to handle 2 dimensional array, sent from angular to php, for database query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, angularjs

I have created a 2 dimensional array order_details in angular that has the following structure:

```
| order_id | product_id |
+==========+============+
|    1     |     2      |
+----------+------------+
|    1     |     3      |
+----------+------------+
|    2     |     4      |
+----------+------------+
|    3     |     2      |
+----------+------------+
```

I used post method to send this array to a php file.

In php file I use the following code to store the array:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$array = $request;
```

I want to execute an update query in mysql using the array like this:

```
UPDATE table_ex SET status='completed' WHERE order_id IN array.order_id AND product_id IN array.product_id
```

Table_ex before the query looks like:

```
| order_id | product_id | status  |
+==========+============+=========+
+----------+------------+---------+
|    5     |     4      | nothing |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    6     |     2      | nothing |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    1     |     2      | nothing |
+----------+------------+---------|
|    1     |     3      | nothing |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    2     |     4      | nothing |
+----------+------------+---------+
|    3     |     2      | nothing |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

After the update the table_ex should look like this:

Table_ex before the query looks like:

```
| order_id | product_id |   status  |
+==========+============+===========+
|    5     |     4      |  nothing  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    6     |     2      |  nothing  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     |     2      | completed |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     |     3      | completed |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    2     |     4      | completed |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    3     |     2      | completed |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

Could you help me!

Thanks in advance,

Giannis

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I added more details to be more specific. You can check it again.

Comment: I still don't see the question. Try adding a question mark to it :P

Comment: Sorry for all this confusion. My question: Is there any way to get each pair (order_id, product_id) from the first table to use it in the where clause of mysql query in php file?

Comment: Finally @syck's answer is working for me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would set order_id=6, product_id=2 to 'completed' as well, because the 2 is in the product_id array. Solve it with OR-joined AND-subconditions like this:

```
$cond = array();
foreach ($array as $part) {
    $cond[] = sprintf('(order_id="%s" AND product_id="%s")', 
        $part['order_id'], $part['product_id']);
}
$sql = 'UPDATE table_ex SET status='completed' WHERE '.join(' OR ', $cond);
```

(Hope I got the structure of your array correctly.)

That will generate a query which looks like

```
UPDATE table_ex SET status='completed' 
  WHERE (order_id="1" AND product_id="2")
  OR (order_id="1" AND product_id="3")
  OR (order_id="2" AND product_id="4")
  OR (order_id="3" AND product_id="2")
```

Comment: Thank you for your try #syck but your answer is not what I exactly want. I would like each pair(order_id, product_id) to be used in the where clause of my query.

Comment: But thats exactly what it does. Possibly your `$array` is organized the other way round (one sub-array of id's under order_id and one under product_id). You did not specify that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that. Your update helped me.